# Using Web API DelegatingHandler in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I wrote a DelegatingHandler to handle cookie based authentication in my Web API project. I now see that I need a few mvc Controllers as well. Can I use the same handler for those? If not, what is the mvc equivalent of a DelegatingHandler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only equivalent is a global filter.

If you use OWIN, it could be possible to use it but this is still at beta.